Query for EGM2008 geoid height at Lat/Long in PostGIS
Problem:
I'm trying to retrieve Geoid height at a latitude longitude via PostGIS using the egm2008 dataset. I've tried multiple locations but keep getting no value returned by my query.
I don't know if I loaded the data improperly, messed up the translate, have the wrong dataset, or if my query is wrong. I've done a fair amount of digging and can't seem to find examples of this workflow. I think the query is my most likely issue but I've included all the steps I took to convert and load the rasters into PostGIS.
Getting the data
Multiple sources are available for the egm2008 data. I ended up using the geographic lib sourceforge rather than https://earth-info.nga.mil/ just due to the later being slow to load.
Once downloaded the egm2008-1.tar.bz2 extracts to egm-2008-1.tar which extracts to a geoids folder which contains egm2008-1.pgm ( this ends up being 455,668 KB versus the the 158,583 KB of the .tar.bz2 so I guess it's worth the annoyance )
Translating the img to GeoTIFF
Unfortunately you can't directly import a .pgm file directly into PostGIS. First the file needs to be translated to a GeoTIFF. Luckily gdal_translate can be used to convert to a GeoTIFF. The command I ran and the response I get are below. Scaling and offset info was from the geographic lib docs and confirmed by opening the .pgm file in a text editor (editor crashes but I can see the first 16 lines containing the header).
input:
gdal_translate -ot Float32 -scale 0 65000 -108 87 egm2008-1.pgm egm2008-1.tif

response:
Input file size is 21600, 10801
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Creating the SQL File
After getting the .tif file for egm2008 I used raster2pgsql to create the SQL inserts.
Creating the SQL file takes a few minutes.
 raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M egm2008-1.tif -F -t 100x100 terrain.geoid_egm2008 > egm2008.sql

Inserting the Data
This part needs improvement as the inserts took ~24hrs  to complete.  I naively ran a psql command and pointed to file I created. I need to see if raster2pgsql can output in batches or it's possible to multithread the inserts via psql. Either way, the inserts worked and eventually finished.
 psql -U postgres -d terrain -a -f egm2008.sql

Querying for Geoid Height
I am running a query which I got from a previous answer here on GIS StackExchange. I've moved the lat long point to a bunch of locations and haven't been able to get a hit anywhere. I think this is the most likely area that I have an issue. I've previously loaded rasters from the ned19 dataset and am able to query using a similar query without the modulus command or the multiplication and cast to numeric.
SELECT ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(mod(-75.49393 + 360,360), 39.96002),4326))::numeric * 0.003 - 108
FROM terrain.geoid_egm2008
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(mod(-75.49393 + 360,360), 39.96002),4326));
--Should be ~ -33.9943

Assuming I was just missing with ST_Intersects I tried the following query and still get no rows returned
SELECT * from (
SELECT ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(mod(-75.49393 + 360,360), 39.96002),4326))::numeric * 0.003 - 108 as val
from terrain.geoid_egm2008)
where val != null

Are you able to point me in the right direction?
